# what's the difference between cordova-plugin-sqlite-2 and cordova-sqlite-storage?

Tags: sqlite, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, pouchdb, ionic-native

In this [tutorial to use SQLite with PouchDB](https://www.techiediaries.com/ionic-sqlite-pouchdb/), the cordova plugin used is `cordova-plugin-sqlite-2`. Meanwhile in [another tutorial to use SQLite in Ionic](https://www.positronx.io/ionic-sqlite-database-crud-app-example-tutorial/), the cordova plugin used is `cordova-sqlite-storage`.

What's actually the difference between the two plugins?

Is it possible to use `cordova-sqlite-storage` with PouchDB instead of `cordova-plugin-sqlite-2` ?

And is it possible to use `cordova-sqlite-plugin-2` when I want to work with Ionic 5 Native SQLite plugin (as the 2nd tutorial)?

---

**UPDATE**:

I tried creating an app that uses PouchDB and I installed `cordova-sqlite-storage` plugin instead of `cordova-plugin-sqlite-2` because I want to use Ionic Native SQLite at the same time. When the app launches, I get an error as below:

```js
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): {"status":500,"name":"web_sql_went_bad","message":"unknown","reason":"Invalid database handle"}
    at resolvePromise (zone-evergreen.js:797:1)
    at resolvePromise (zone-evergreen.js:754:1)
    at zone-evergreen.js:858:1
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:391:1)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:34182:1)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:390:1)
    at Zone.runTask (zone-evergreen.js:168:1)
```

I have also installed `pouchdb-adapter-cordova-sqlite` in my project. According to [pouchdb-adapter-cordova-sqlite](https://github.com/pouchdb-community/pouchdb-adapter-cordova-sqlite), it should work with `cordova-sqlite-storage` as well as stated;

> PouchDB adapter using native Cordova SQLite as its backing store. It
> works with any one of the following Cordova plugins:
>
> - Cordova-sqlite-storage
> - cordova-plugin-sqlite-2
> - cordova-plugin-websql

Why did I get that error when I switched to using `cordova-sqlite-storage`?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure to have only ONE of the plugins.

The error that I got seems to be caused by both plugins existing inside the `package.json`. I thought I've removed it by using the `ionic cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-sqlite-2` but when I removed and added the platform again, and run `ionic cordova run android -l`, the error still showed up and inside the package.json, apparently `cordova-plugin-sqlite-2` was still available.

Checked inside the `config.xml` and removed it from there, removed and added the platform, error disappeared.